# Error Excel ConnectionString 64 bit C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017

Estoy tratando de importar la información de una worksheet de Excel a un datatable. si la versión de Excel/Windows System es de 32bits no tengo problema, me realizada el proceso con el siguiente 
 Connection String: `string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';Data Source=", fileName);`
Pero cuando ejecuto el código en una máquina de 64bits con Excel de 64bits con el siguiente 
Connection String :`string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';Data Source=", fileName);` me sale el siguiente error: "*Could not find installable ISAM*". 
Con el de 32 bits tampoco funciona.
Se que el error es del Connection String pero no consigo dar con la tecla por mucho que miro por internet y foros.
Propiedades:
Aplicación desarrolada en Visual Studio 2017
OS: 32bits
Archivo excel: .xlsm
Platform target: Any CPU (*necesito que funcione tanto para 32 como 64 bits*)
Se que el error es del Connection String.
Alguien tiene alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya he conseguido solucionarlo.
En Visual, clic botón dcho sobre la solución y le damos a "*Manage NutGet Packages...*"
Buscamos el paquete *ClosedXml* y lo instalamos.
Este paquete es una referencia para la gestión de los Excel que es de bastante ayuda.
Cualquier cosa me decís.
Un saludo